# WCF error message - method <name> not supported on Proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

As a matter of fact I already found a solution to my problem, But I am just curious.

I came across the following error message 
" The method UnlockObject is not supported on this proxy. It can happen if the method is not marked with OperationContractAttribute or if the interface type is not marked with ServiceContractAttribute"

here is my interface :

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IServeurCallback), SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IServeur
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
   void UnlockObject<T>(Guid ClientId, ObjectId toUnlock, string collectionName);
   [...]
}
```

How it is implemented in my server

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Serveur : Proxy.IServeur
{
   public void UnlockObject<T>(Guid ClientId, ObjectId toUnlock, string collectionName)
   {
      /*stuff using <T>*/
   }
}
```

and how it is called from my client

```
if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Projet")
    this.channel.UnlockObject<ProjectClass.Project>(client._Guid, toSend, "collection_Project");
else if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Object")
    this.channel.UnlockObject<Object.c_Object>(client._Guid, toSend, "collection_Object");
else if (this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ObjString")
    this.channel.UnlockObject<ObjString.ObjString>(client._Guid, toSend, "collection_ObjString");
```

(this.channel was created this way

```
 DuplexChannelFactory<Proxy.IServeur> factory;
 /* do stuff to make it usable */
 Proxy.IServeur channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

I solved this by removing the

```
<T>
```

from all the function. Now my code is a little bit dirtier, but it is working fine

Why does this error message show up ?

Comment: If you post the solution, we may be able to tell you *why* it happened.  Otherwise it's a guessing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have exception because `wsdl` does not support open generic types and so `WCF` service cannot expose them on operation contracts as it uses `wsdl` to expose metadata of your operations.

It is possible to expose bounded generics in your code (see [details](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx)) or since the `<T>` argument only identifies the type you can add it as another argument

```
 [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
 void UnlockObject(Type objectType,Guid ClientId, ObjectId toUnlock, string collectionName);
```